# Application gets ANR when trying to change *.mpd tracks

Tags: chromecast

I'm trying to implement in my app chrome-cast. I'm using the following libs :

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.9.6'
 implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-cast:2.7.0'
```

My videos are encrypted DRM. I provide to my custom receiver stream URL and proxy URL. The video is played on TV using a chrome cast. The problem appears when I try to change my video/sub-tracks. Using the ExpandedControllerActivity provided by prev libs I can trigger/close the native dialog that shows my video and subtitles tracks. But I get ANR when I choose another track.